# AWS CLI S3 Sync exclude not working in script, directly in terminal it does

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, centos, sh, aws-cli

I'm trying to create a shell-script to manage my sync with a s3-bucket.
Here is what is in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 sync $1 $2 $(for word in $(echo "$excludeconf"| tr ";" " "); do echo -n "--exclude \"$word\" "; done) $del --no-follow-symlinks $3
```

`$1` is source 
`$2` is destination
`$3` is another parameter that gets passed (dryrun). the `$(word...` takes a list of files & folders `$excludeconf` and creates `--exclude ...` with them.

If I run the script it won't exclude anything.

If I put an `echo` in front of the command above, I get this:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://BUCKETNAME/FOLDERNAME/ --exclude .SOMEFILE --exclude "public/icon/*" --delete --no-follow-symlinks --dryrun
```

If I copy that command and run it manualy inside the terminal it works just fine.

Any ideas?

FYI: I'm running CentOS 7

Edit:

after some tests I found out the problem is globbing: the public/icon/* gets interpreted to public/icon/folder1 public/icon/folder2 If I try to set noglob it won't work.. is ist because it is inside $(..)?

Comment: how are you running the script when it does not work? The dot may be interpreted differently in that case.

Comment: I added it (#!/bin/bash)

Comment: ok, but how is it executed. cron?

Comment: Add a `--debug` parameter and see what it says. (And you probably want to remove `--dryrun`)

Comment: This is basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables , and the solution is the same: use an array.

Comment: I execute it manuela ./script.sh; I'll try debug later. dryrun/or not makes no difference.

Comment: after some tests I found out the problem is globbing: the `public/icon/*` gets interpreted to `public/icon/folder1  public/icon/folder2`
If I try to set noglob it won't work.. is ist because it is inside `$(..)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten the script in python and changed it to:

```
os.system("set -f noglob && aws s3.....")
```

That worked.